# Are there any C APIs to extract the base file name from its full path in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

Given the full path, the API should give me the base file name. E.g., "/foo/bar.txt" --> "bar.txt".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's [basename()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/basename) .

Feed it with a path (in the form of a `char*`) and it will return you the base name (that is the name of the file/directory you want) in the form of another `char*` .

EDIT:

I forgot to tell you that the POSIX version of `basename()` modifies its argument. If you want to avoid this you can use the GNU version of `basename()` prepending this in your source:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
```

In exchange this version of `basename()` will return an empty string if you feed it with, e.g. `/usr/bin/` because of the trailing slash.

Comment: strdup-ing the path before feeding it to basename() instead.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, the `include` should be `<libgen.h>`.

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <string.h>

char *basename(char const *path)
{
    char *s = strrchr(path, '/');
    if (!s)
        return strdup(path);
    else
        return strdup(s + 1);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to free the newly allocated buffer: "man strdup" says: "Memory for the new string is obtained with malloc(3), and can be freed with free(3)". Remove ":" after "else".

Answer (score 5):

You want basename(), which should be present on pretty much any POSIX-ish system:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/basename.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int main() {
  char name[] = "/foo/bar.txt";
  printf("%s\n", basename(name));
  return 0;
}
```

...

```
$ gcc test.c
$ ./a.out
bar.txt
$
```

Comment: basename is destructive and will cause a segfault in this case, try `basename("/foo/bar/")`.

Comment: @roe: Actually it _may_ segfault in _that_ case. In my case, it was fine. :) But you're right, fixed.

Comment: yes, naturally, sorry. I meant it MIGHT segfault in your case, assuming the string literal is some compile-time macro or something. The whole point being it might be destructive, and you're forced to make a copy of your string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct C code of @matt-joiner should be:

```
char *basename(char const *path)
{
        char *s = strrchr(path, '/');
        if(s==NULL) {
                return strdup(path);
        } else {
                return strdup(s + 1);
        }
}
```

Comment: `!s` is idiomatic C code, compared to `s==NULL` which is superfluous.